# What is a reasonable manufactured solution to test finite difference method?

Tags: pde, finite-difference, elliptic-pde

What is a reasonable manufactured solution to test the following equation against its finite difference approximation? I want it to look like a Cosine function about $0$, rotated about $Z$ axis (basically not varying about $\theta$) such that $f$  turns out to be a not so bad function in terms of $r,\theta$

$$u_{rr} \;+\; \frac{1}{r} u_r \;+\; \frac{1}{r^2} u_{\theta\theta}\;+\; Cu \;=\; f(r,\theta)$$

Also, it should avoid the discontinuity at $r = 0$

Comment: Hi @mod0 and welcome to scicomp!  Your question appears to be virtually identical to one posted eariler: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/guidelines-for-choosing-manufactured-solutions-for-numerical-pde-schemes

Comment: Hi Paul, I have seen that question and even gone over the document attached in the answer. The document does not deal with a source term. And hence I asked anyway. I meant,  I went to the MASA site, downloaded their document and went over it.

Comment: In the method of manufactured solutions, the source term is obtained from the prescribed solution.  It's not really feasible to expect to control the properties of the source term $f(r,\theta)$ from a given solution.  More importantly, is there an important reason you need to control these properties?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I meant the $Cu$ term.

Comment: Most of the heat equation in polar has only the first three terms. I was wondering what would happen if a $Cu$ term is also present. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing magic happens. You just plug your chosen $u$ into the PDE and see what $f$ it generates. Implement that and the BCs, and you're set.

Comment: Also, you should choose a more complex manufactured solution than a simple cosine function about the origin. If your manufactured solution has no $\theta$ variation, you will not test the $u_{\theta\theta}$ term's implementation at all. You should include a product of transcendental functions at the very least.

Comment: something like $(1-r^3) cos(\theta)^2$ ?

Comment: You should not use a polynomial in $r$. Use trancendentals in both directions at the very least.